# How to automatically invite an IAM user via email after creating account using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm creating an IAM user programmatically using `boto3`.

I also want to invite the user that I've just created using email.

Here's what I've tried so far for creating and updating the password.

```
iam.create_user(UserName='username')
iam.create_login_profile(
    UserName='username',
    Password='password',
    PasswordResetRequired=False
)
```

But I haven't found an option to automatically send an invite email to the user after it's been created.

Is there any way to automatically send an invite mail with the password and so that user can login?

Something like

```
invite_mail='somemail'
```

Comment: Since you're already using boto3, have you tried using either SNS or SES to send out an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built AWS capability to send users their login information.

In fact, there is not even a standard field for storing email addresses for IAM Users.

You would need to code such functionality yourself.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I've been using. I was sending mails using `send_mail()` in Django. I was just thinking if there's any other way to do it using boto3. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

## 1

You can use a cloud trail to trigger Lambda upon the IAM-user creation event and send email to newly created users using AWS SES client. You can validate the format of the email with a regex like abc.xyx@company.com. This you can only do if the user name is in email format.

## 2

```
import boto3

import logging

ses_client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1')

iam_client = boto3.client('iam')


response = iam_client.create_user(
    Path='string',
    UserName='string',
    PermissionsBoundary='string',
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
)

#if username as email id 
user_email =  response['User']['UserName']

#if user has tagged with email

#user_email =  response['User']['Tags']['KeyName']

SMTP_FROM = 'EMAIL_ADDRESS'

html = "html_email_template"

SMTP_TO = user_email

try:
    response = ses_client.send_email(
        Source=SMTP_FROM,
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': SMTP_TO 
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': "UTF-8",
                    'Data': html,
                }
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Data': 'New User Created '
            }
        }
    )
    logger.info(response)
except ClientError as e:
    logger.error(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    logger.info("Email sent! Message ID: " + response['MessageId'])
```